# MySQL Insert before Delete

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a simple webchat server. I have a two tables:
**chatMsgs:**

- RowId
- Username
- Time
- Action
- Target
- Message

**onlineUsers:**

- Username
- Action
- LastActive

How would I go about removing any row from onlineUsers where online.LastActive < %t%-120 and for any item removed from onlineUsers, I would like to add a new row to chatMsgs where

```
Username=onlineUsers.username,
LastAction='logout',
Time=%t%,
Message='Timed out after 2min'
```

%t% is just a place holder which will be replaced with php's time() return value. If possible, I'd like to do this with a single call to the mysqli_query handler, though the query string can contain multiple directives for the mysql server

The following works afaik(haven't throughly tested), but I was wondering if there was a better way:

```
<?php
    // $db is an mysqli database link.

    $t = time()
    $e = $t - 120,
    $q = "SELECT Username FROM onlineUsers WHERE LastActive<={$e};",
    $r = $db->query($q);

    if (!$r)
        die('db error');

    elseif ($r->num_rows > 0) {
        $q = '';

        $r = $r->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
        for ($n in $r)
            $q .= "INSERT INTO chatMsg(Username,Time,Action,Message) VALUES('{$n}',{$t},'Logout','Timed out after 2min');";

        $q .= "DELETE FROM onlineUsers WHERE LastActive<={$e};";

        $r = $db->query($q);
        if (!$r) 
            die('db error');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Um well, in two statements? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this all in a single SQL statement, then the following should suffice (using your $t and $e variables from above):

```
INSERT INTO chatMsg(Username, Time, Action, Message)
SELECT Username, {$t}, 'logout', 'Timed out after 2 mins'
FROM onlineUsers
WHERE LastActive <= {$e};

DELETE FROM onlineUsers WHERE LastActive <= {$e};
```

Note that it's possible for a race condition to occur - if the user performs some activity between the INSERT and DELETE statements, they will still be removed from the onlineUsers table.  You could get around this loading all of the "to be removed" entries, calling the deletes first, then adding the logout messages, but this is contrary to your original requirement.

Comment: I just want to be able to update the chatMsgs table and remove the users from onlineUsers in the same statement. The order of processing doesn't matter to me. How would I go about reversing it so the delete could happen prior to inserting as to not cause a race condition?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Queries:

```
INSERT INTO chatMsgs
VALUES ($username, $time, "logout", $target, $message);

DELETE FROM onlineUsers
WHERE Username = $username;
```